# How to remove a context variable in Watson Assistant service on IBM Cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am using this, but this only sets it to empty,

```
{
  "context": {
    "time": "",
    "place": "",
    "things": "",
    "transport": ""
  },
  "output": {}
}
```

I also tried `"time": "null"` and `"time": "$time.remove"`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**For those using Watson Assistant on an older API version:**

The best is to use [`context.remove()` in the output section](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-runtime.html#context-delete). I usually have an extra child node for cleanup.

```
{
  "output": {
    "text": {},
    "deleted": "<? context.remove('eventName') ?> <? context.remove('queryPredicate') ?>"
  }
}
```

Because `deleted` is not part of the context section it won't be carried forward.

**For those on recent API versions of Watson Assistant:**

Set the variable to null. Here is the doc on ["Deleting a context variable"](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-runtime#dialog-runtime-context-delete).

```
{
  "context": {
    "myvariable": null
  }
}
```

Setting the variable to null can also be performed in the dialog form when assigning values to variables.

Comment: If we add child node and empty the context variable there, it gets removed before the response triggers thus causing the variable to be missed in response. Do you know a solution to this problem?

Comment: Could you ask this as new question and add details?

Comment: @Airtrag I updated my answer to reflect the different API versions. The method has changed with newer API versions.

Answer (score 3):

You can also add a child node and add jump to the child node after response with the condition set to true and set the context variable to null there.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the following does what you want.

```
{
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "Ok got it: $Var1, $Var2, $Var3. <? $Var1 = NULL ?> <? $Var2 = NULL ?> <? $Var3 = NULL ?>"
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    }
  }
}
```