# IBM Watson Assistant / Conversation : The output displays the last search

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation, ibm-cloud-functions

I have developed cloud functions and am using 'generic output' with image response types, as well as text. However when I search for a product (which uses my cloud function), the last result appears.

For example:

> Me: Buy Classic now
>
> Bot: Name: Classic, Price: 4.99, Description: Classic description

But when I search for another product

> Me: Buy Extra now

the bot will display

> Bot: Name: Classic, Price: 4.99, Description: Classic description

Only until another search instance does it refresh and display the correct result.

```
{
  "context": {
    "name": "",
    "counter": 0
  },
  "output": {
    "generic": [
      {
        "values": [
          {
            "text": "Found  Products"
          }
        ],
        "response_type": "text",
        "selection_policy": "sequential"
      },
      {
        "title": "<? $result.body.items[0].name ?>",
        "source": "http://**********/pub/media/catalog/product<? $result.body.items[0].custom_attributes[5].value ?>",
        "description": "$<? $result.body.items[0].price ?>",
        "response_type": "image"
      },
      {
        "title": "Select one of the following options",
        "options": [
          {
            "label": "Order a subscription",
            "value": {
              "input": {
                "text": "Order a subscription"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "label": "More Details",
            "value": {
              "input": {
                "text": "More Details"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "response_type": "option"
      }
    ]
  },
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "/**********@gmail.com_dev/getProducts2",
      "type": "server",
      "parameters": {
        "url": "<?entities.products[0].literal?>"
      },
      "credentials": "$my_creds",
      "result_variable": "context.result"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you post the example JSON part that is calling the cloud function. Obviously remove any user/pass/sensitive data.

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty yes I updated it

Comment: See this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48543487/how-to-remove-a-context-variable-in-watson-conversation-service-on-ibm-cloud

Comment: So I have to remove 'result_variable' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. I put the output text in a child node instead of the parent node. No need to remove any context variable.