# Repeating an intent causes slot validation to consider previous value

Tags: watson-conversation

I have an `#StartTest` intent which expects a `@Test` entity (user examples: "Start test", "Start @Test") , then I created a slot that checks if `@Test` has been provided (`$Test` variable), and if not, it asks for it.

The problem is that if I type "Start test", provide the test name, and type "Start test" again, it considers the previous `$Test` value in the condition, thus considering it as already provided.

How can I ask for a new value for `$Test` if the user send "Start test" again?

Comment: Have you considered removing the variable after its first use?

Comment: How do you suggest? I just cleaned up the variable like I said in my answer below and got it working, but maybe you know a different way.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48543487/how-to-remove-a-context-variable-in-watson-conversation

Comment: Great. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding a child node and setting the variables in the Context Editor or JSON Editor.

[image: Example from the IBM docs]