# Can't modify user_defined context with Watson Assistant API v2

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I'm trying to migrate chatbot to use newly introduced **Assistant API v2**.

My chatbot infrastructure includes Middleware services which modifies the *context* after getting the response from Watson. In some case I used to remove particular properties from the context and it worked fine. However I noticed that after migration to **API v2** this approach does not work anymore as the deleted properties are somehow stored on **Watson** side.

For example I received following *context* from Watson:

```
{
    "assistantId": "---",
    "sessionId": "---",
    "messageInput": {
        "Text": "Some text",
        "Options": {
            "Debug": "true",
            "ReturnContext": "true",
            "Restart": "false"
        }
    },
    "context": 
    {
        "Global": "null",
        "Skills": {
            "AdditionalProperties": {
                "main skill": {
                    "user_defined": {
                        "id": "23",
                        "description": "Dont know"
                    },
                    "system": {---}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I remove *'description'* from the context and send request to Watson once more. Surprisingly *'description'* is still there with the same value ('Dont know').

Possible solution would be not to remove a property but to set it's value to empty string. But even in this case my dialog does not work correctly as Watson somehow stores the point in dialog it was visiting previously (or not, these are my guesses). I assume it might be related to system.state property which stores an encoded state of the dialog (again - or not).

My question is why is dialog behaving this way? 
How does it store the context information so I can't remove properties from *user_defined* context?
And how can I reset dialog state to initial keeping the same *conversation_id* (*session_id*)?

P.S. I'm using **Watson API v2**: 2020-04-01

Comment: Where in the message  object do you have the  user-defined context? Could you add the sample JSON?

Comment: @data_henrik I have edited the question to provide full context.

Comment: Does it help when instead of removing you set the context variable to `null`?

Comment: Right, it has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48543487/how-to-remove-a-context-variable-in-watson-assistant-service-on-ibm-cloud

Comment: No, it does not, unfortunately. Setting variable to `null` or empty string has no effect.  @MichalBida

Comment: I mean It does set the property to null but dialog still works incorrectly. And when I switch to API v1 everything works fine.

Comment: @OstapMoravskyi Any solution for the above ?